# Class Room Demo Scene Black Windows?

Tags: error

I just wonder if anyone know how to fix this issue? When I render the Class Room Scene, the windows often shown up as black (or checker boxes)? Apparently the ray tracing part is not hitting anything at those regions?

However, when I look at the demo image from the website they have corrected those? Any ideas? [image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. The black is actually Alpha. So the quickest way to fix it is to patch it up with white.

Also, I notice the final result used the composite feature! It was not enabled by default. And that's why it looked different.

Comment: I have the same problem but I don't understand your solution. What do you mean by "patch it up with white"? How do you do that? I have tried to change the material but it is still the same. Also I don't understand what you mean by "enable the composite feature". Where can I do that? If you could elaborate on that I would be grateful.